# Why don't the wrapper classes for Primitives have a setter?

Tags: java, wrapper, setter, primitive-types, immutability

What is the reason why Wrapper classes (like Integer, Double, etc.) don't have a setter for their inner primitive value ?

I am asking this because that kind of functionality would have simplified calculus, and have made the Java language a little more flexible .

Let me give you some examples.

**1) Let's take the following example:**

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
x++;
```

The previous code behind the scenes is performing autoboxing . Something like:

```
int x_tmp = x.intValue();
x_tmp++;
x = new Integer(x_tmp); // Yes that's a new memory allocation
```

Because of this problem doing calculus on Wrapper is slower than performing on plain primitive types. With a setter it would've been more easy to increment the inner value, without allocating another object on the heap.

**2) Another issue that is bugging me is that is impossible in Java to write a swap function like I can do in C (using pointers) or in C++ (pointers or references).**

If i write `void swap(Integer x, Integer y)` I cannot acces the inner value because, and It is going to be impossible for me to swap the values.

PS:
A friend of mine suggested that i should consider the bigger picture, and think in terms of concurrency and type immutability.

So do you have an explanation for this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) With a setter, the wrapper types would be mutable. Immutability is a good thing in many ways... threading, general understandability of the code etc. Personally I think it's a shame that `Calendar` and `Date` are mutable, for example.

In fact, your expansion of `x++;` isn't quite right - it uses `Integer.valueOf` which *doesn't* always create a new value. For example:

```
Integer x = 5;
x++;
Integer y = 5;
y++;

// This prints true    
System.out.println(x == y); // Compare references
```

Only a limited range of `Integer` values are cached like this (the spec defines what values *must* behave this way, but allows for a wider range if the JRE wishes to do so)... but it does mean that it won't always be creating a new object.

2) Yes, Java doesn't have pass by reference. Frankly I very rarely find that to be a problem. How often do you really need to swap the values of variables?

Comment: It's not about only about swapping. There are other cases when I think a problem in some way, and then I realize i have to rethink the problem.

Comment: @Andrei: Usually I find that encourages me to encapsulate related values in a separate type, which is a good idea anyway. Just how often do you find yourself wanting it?

Comment: So immutability is only for protecting the "programmer" and to ease his / her work ?

Comment: @Andrei: Well sort of... like encapsulation, garbage collection, polymorphism etc are "only" to make the programmer's life easier. In my experience it's a *huge* advantage in many situations.

Answer (score 6):

Wrapper classes are usually not used unless you need to put them into a collection. If they were mutable it would make problems if used inside sets and as keys for hashtables.

Sets and hashtables need the hash value to be always the same.

Comment: I guess it should've been the programmer responsibility not the language. But hey, I am just starting to learn java in a more organized way.

Comment: It's not just wrapper classes:  we had some issues awhile back with some non-trivial classes being used as cache keys.  These classes were mutable (worse still, had ONLY default constructors) and sure enough at some point someone (well, me) re-used some keys by changing their values.  The resulting bug fix included making those key classes immutable...

Answer (score 4):

Caching Integers in the range from -128 to 127 requires immutable Integers. Consider the follwoing code:

```
Integer id = Integer.valueOf(1);  // a new Integer, cached in Integer class

// and somewhere else

Integer key = Integer.valueOf(1);  // returns the cached value
```

Now *if* Integer was mutable and had a setter and someone did

```
key.setValue(2);  // not legal Java code, just for demonstration
```

this would change the value of `id` too and, to a lot of peoples surprise:

```
Integer one = Integer.valueOf(1);
if (one != 1)
   System.out.println("Surprise! I know, you expected `1`, but ...");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, Strings and wrapper classes are designed as immutable to avoid accidental changes to the data. You can check the below article for further information.

[Why Strings and Wrapper classes are immutable in java?](http://www.explain-java.com/2013/03/06/is-string-mutable-in-java-why-wrapper-classes-immutable-in-java/)